# Face detection for two faces-Cascade opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection

I am working on with the Face detection using cascade Classifier in opencv python. Its working fine. But i want to develop my code to detect only one face and also the largest face only to detect.

Comment: We need to see what you have already, and how you've tried to make your code detect only the largest face. We can't look over your shoulder at the code you have, so we don't know how it works, and therefore can't suggest a correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the detected faces by size and keep the biggest one only?